# Why do $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n$ and $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n(x-a)^n|$ always have the same radius of convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I read this statement in a calculus book today and it says this statement is true because of the ratio test. Well I can understand that whenever $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n(x-a)^n|$ converges, $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n$ must also converge, but the theorem does not say that whenever $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n(x-a)^n|$ diverges $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n$ diverges, so logically speaking it is possible that the radius of convergence of $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n(x-a)^n|$ is smaller than that of $\sum \limits _{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n$. But why and how is it guaranteed that this cannot happen?

Comment: Have you tried the root test?

Comment: If $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum c_n (x-a)^{n}$ then  $\sum |c_n (x-a)^{n}|<\infty$  if $|x-a| <R$.

Comment: @Gary No but the nth root test also requires the series to have all nonnegative terms.

Comment: The radius of convergence is the greatest upper bound of $|x-a|,$ for which $\lim_nc_n(x-a)^n=0$ or $c_n(x-a)^n$ is bounded..

Comment: @AndyZ That is not true.

Comment: @Gary it says on the textbook though

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I agree but why is the radius of convergence for absolute convergence necessarily the same as the radius of convergence of $\sum c_n(x-a)^n$?

Comment: Yes, because $a_n\to 0$ iff $|a_n|\to 0,$ in particular for $a_n=c_n(x-a)^n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc hahahaha thank you so much! I get it now!